# ERROR: Attempting to call cordova.exec() before 'deviceready'. Ignoring

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm trying to "PhoneGap" (1.7.0) a jQuery Mobile app (1.1.0) I have to create an Android app. However, I keep getting the following alert message.

```
ERROR: Attempting to call cordova.exec() before 'deviceready'. Ignoring.
```

It appears as if this I change pages (change for example index.1.htm to index.2.htm)

I'm not making any calls to Cordova functions in my app - it's pure JQM.

Any ideas what the problem is. Or, failing that, does anyone know why cordova.exec() might be called during an $.ajax request?

I'm running the app under Android 4.0.3, in a virtual device/simulator. Also try to run at Android 2.1, and 2.33 simulator device, getting this same error!

Comment: Please tell clearly .....are you navigating to a different html ...or something else .......

Answer (score 20):

Ensure that you are using the appropriate version of cordova-1.x.0.js (or phonegap.js)

Each platform uses a different version of the file.

This error coming up sometimes can mean you're using the iOS version in an Android application.

Comment: I was getting the same error with 1.7.0 and this was the fix for me. Yep, I brought over my iOS JavaScript files (not the HTML and CSS of course) to finish the Android version just like @dkeeghan warns of. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

It happens when you include incorrect version of cordova.js. Please check your cordova version. I had two cordova files in my www folder and got this error. Removed the inappropriate one and its working.